# rename file without original name

Tags: php, html, image-uploading, file-rename

Am uploading multiple file using single input  and rename name it everything works fine

i tried to rename so i used `$newname = md5(rand() * time());` and works fine **but** i want the file to **rename without original name**

### CODE

```
if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $file_name = $key . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $desired_dir = "user_data/";
        if (empty($errors) == true) {
            if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if (is_dir("$desired_dir/" . $file_name) == false) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $newname . $file_name);
            } else {                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir = "$desired_dir/" . $newname . $file_name;
                rename($file_tmp, $new_dir);
            }
        } else {
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }
```

this code works fine the output file is saved as `26c73b3b8da05352340ad62a913fa26601uploadingfile.jpg`

**What i need is** `26c73b3b8da05352340ad62a913fa26601.jpg` i just want to skip original file name

### Output:

```
$file1 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][0]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][0] : null;
$file2 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][1]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][1] : null;
$file3 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][2]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][2] : null;
$file4 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][3]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][3] : null;
$file5 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][4]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][4] : null;
```

Comment: $new_dir = "$desired_dir/" . $newname;

Comment: @MarcoMura i tried but file is saved without extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $uploadedFiles = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $errors = array();
        $file_name = md5(uniqid("") . time());
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

        if($file_type == "image/gif"){
            $sExt = ".gif";
        } elseif($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg"){
            $sExt = ".jpg";
        } elseif($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png"){
            $sExt = ".png";
        }
        if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif','.jpg','.png'))) {
            $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
        }
        if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $desired_dir = "user_data/";
        if (empty($errors)) {
            if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt)) {
                $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($file_name . $sExt, 1);
            } else {
                echo "Couldn't upload file " . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
                $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($_FILES['files']['name'][$key], 0);
            }
        } else {
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }

    foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
        if (!empty($row[1])) {
            $codestr = '$file' . ($key+1) . ' = $row[0];';
            eval ($codestr);
        } else {
            $codestr = '$file' . ($key+1) . ' = NULL;';
            eval ($codestr);
        }
    }
}

echo $file1;
echo $file2;
echo $file3;
echo $file4;
echo $file5;
?>
```

Comment: how to display all uploaded image name

Comment: By storing the uploaded file name each time it succeed. Check my edited answer.

Comment: btw, you can't always change what you want in your question after you receive correct answers. this will cause deletion for your post.

Comment: please can you help me i just need to `echo` file name as `file name1` and `file name2` etc

Comment: yes i need to echo upload file name in `$file1=one image name;` `$file2=second image name;` `$file3=3rd image name;` `$file4=4th image name;` `file5=5th image name;` because i allow only 5 images so i need to display 5 image name in seperate variable

Comment: i get error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier (T_STRING) `

Comment: I tried it myself, and it's working. What line is getting error?

Comment: i don't see file echo and i get ERROR `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_225627080981095_1694244120189' (T_STRING) in C:\Users\logon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\upload file rename single and multiple\multiple file rename\method 2\process.php(43) : eval()'d code on line 1`

Comment: i made some changes and it works but am unable to display rename name i get original name displayed

Comment: i made some changes and that works but it displays only original file name not he renamed file name

Answer (score 4):

You get the file extension this way

```
 $path = pathinfo($filename);
 // this is how you remove the original filename and keep the extension
 $newname = md5(rand() * time()) . '.' . $path['extension'];
```

and this is your code edited

```
  if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
      $errors = array();
      foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
          $file_name = $key . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
          /// file parts
          $path = pathinfo($file_name);
          /// extenstion
          $ext = $path['extension'];
          // this is how you remove the original filename and keep the extension (overwrite $file_name)
          $file_name = md5(rand() * time()) .'.'. $path['extension'];

          $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
          $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
          $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
          if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
              $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
          }
          $desired_dir = "user_data/";
          if (empty($errors) == true) {
              if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                  mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
              }
              if (is_dir("$desired_dir/" . $file_name) == false) {
                  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name);
              } else {                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                  $new_dir = "$desired_dir/" . $file_name;
                  rename($file_tmp, $new_dir);
              }
          } else {
              print_r($errors);
          }
      }      

  }
?>
```

Comment: i tried file is saved but it doest contain extension means a empty file there is no extension

Comment: can you make small changes in code i need to `echo` all file name with extension

Comment: just write `echo $newname`

Comment: check my code above i have added putput`$file1``$file2``$file3``$file4``$file5` to display each file name i need in this maner so that i can save file name to `SQL`

Comment: how to upload all uploaded image name

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$renamed_file_name = $newname.orginal name. $extension;

str_replace('original_file_name', '', $renamed_file_name);
```

It will replace original file name with blank and you will get filename without original filename

Comment: can you please make full code because am bit confused about your code where to change and what to do

Comment: please check my code above and make change according to it because i have only `. $newname . $file_name;` `file_name` is with extension so i need to extract extension from file name

Answer (score 0):

U can try explode the tmp file in two part the name and the extention and then when giving new name like time().$ext

Sorry cant provide more info right now because im with mobile app but i'will post it tomorrow.